# Forcing a user to crop the featured image in a certain aspect ratio

Tags: post-thumbnails, cropping

I am developing a child theme where I want my featured image to be 3:1, so I won't have my whole page filled with the remainder of the image.

Is there a way to force the user to crop in this aspect ratio when selecting a featured image?

Comment: There is a `save_post()` hook.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post.   You could use this to test the properties of the featured image and alert the user perhaps.

Comment: I have seen this with some plugins, once you select the image the call to action button says select and crop. It takes you to the image editor with a aspect ratio locked crop mask that you can adjust. I too am trying to figure out how to get that.

Comment: Simular question with screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230319/wordpress-media-library-crop-image-on-insert-like-header-image-cropper